# how to install & set up RoR application on shared hosting

Tags: installation, ruby-on-rails, shared-hosting

I successfully installed redmine.org application under my BlueHost account. I was following the [official installation guide](http://www.redmine.org/wiki/1/RedmineInstall) without any error. Point #8 says that I can test the installation by running WEBrick web server and accessing it via lynx http://localhost:3000/ from the Bluehost server. Well it works but when I try from outside I got "parking page".

I contacted BH support and was told that it is because I still have default.html (0B of size) in the root directory. That I need to replace it with index.html from the RoR application. I guess I have to do something about .htaccess and dispatch.fcgi that are in public directory of redmine.

- I created new 'redmine' subdomain under my account. It created new 'redmine' directory inside `~/public_html/`
- then I [checked out the source code](http://www.redmine.org/wiki/redmine/CheckingoutRedmine) inside `~/public_html/redmine` so I have `~/public_html/redmine/public` directory

Q1: did I install redmine source code in the correct directory?
Q2: what can I do to make redmine accessible world wide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
put your code in ~/redmine
backup a ~/redmine/public directory
make symlink of ~/public_html to ~/redmine/public
put backup contents to ~/redmine/public
```

Comment: @varjo: I don't know how to make the symlink. I have two directories `/home5/onalllev/redmine/public/` and `/home5/onalllev/public_html/redmine/` where `/home5/onalllev/public_html` contains all my domains and subdomains. I guess that /home5/onalllev/public_html/redmine should contains all the files that are in `/home5/onalllev/redmine/public/` right now. But I do not know how to do it. Should both directories exist when running `ln -s`? What is the exact syntax. I tried but I am just getting public inside `/home5/onalllev/public_html/redmine/

Comment: okay, try this:
put redmine into /home5/onalllev/redmine
move /home5/onalllev/redmine/public to /home5/onalllev/redmine/public1
make symlink for public_html  by this command:
ln -s /home5/onalllev/redmine/public /home5/onalllev/public_html/redmine/
move all contents from /home5/onalllev/redmine/public1 to /home5/onalllev/redmine/public and remove public1 dir

Comment: @varjo: that is exactly what I was doing. But it creates @public link inside `/home5/onalllev/public_html/redmine/` is that what we want? The `/home5/onalllev/public_html/redmine/` directory has to exist otherwise I get an error.

Comment: I created new question for that http://serverfault.com/questions/166285/how-to-create-a-simlink-to-a-directory

Comment: it looks much better now http://redmine.onalllevels.com/ at least I get some error ;-)

Comment: hm, the trick with `http://localhost:3000` still works without any error. I can get nice welcome page

Comment: please, show your database.yml(without passwords ;) ) and environment.rb

Comment: @varjo: I uncommented #ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= production and it woooooooooooorking now. Thank you for you help!!!

Comment: enjoy with redmine ;)

Comment: @varjo: I've just started.Never used it before but it looks great. Now I need to set up svn over http :-)