# how to create a simlink to a directory?

Tags: linux, symbolic-link

this question is coming from my other [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/166195/how-to-installed-set-up-ror-application-on-shared-hosting) and I need help to make this work. I was trying out for some time and couldn't make it work.

I have a directory inside redmine instalation `/home5/onalllev/redmine/public/` and I need the entire content of this directory to be linked to `/home5/onalllev/public_html/redmine/` so I can access the redmine application via web browser.

I thought that `ln -s /home5/onalllev/redmine/public /home5/onalllev/public_html/redmine/` will do the job but it creates `public` directory inside `/home5/onalllev/public_html/redmine/`. I need all the files from `/home5/onalllev/redmine/public/` to be visible when I do  `cd /home5/onalllev/public_html/redmine/`

- If I am inside the onalllev/public_html/redmine/ and do the ln and the `/home5/onalllev/public_html/redmine/` doesn't exist I get an error: 
  `ln: target /home5/onalllev/public_html/redmine/ is not a directory: No such file or directory`
- If the directory exists I get a directory called public inside redmine directory

Server configuration

- **Linux boxxxx.bluehost.com 2.6.28-10.40.intel.IGB.BHsmp #1 SMP Thu May 20 13:14:49 MDT 2010 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux**
- man ln says that ln is **ln 5.97** (I hope it's the ln version)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

: )
remove your /home5/onalllev/public_html/redmine/ dir
and

```
ln -s /home5/onalllev/redmine/public /home5/onalllev/public_html/redmine
```

Comment: it seems to me that the trick was that I had to be inside `/home5/onalllev/public_html/` and then run ln command